# Trying to understand the concept of "Message metre size"

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am going though the Azure IoT Hub pricing page here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/iot-hub/#pricing

The page introduces the concept of "Message metre size":

[image]

What exactly does "Message metre size" means?

When I choose the Free tier, does that mean I am not able to send payload larger than `0.5 KB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message metre size refers to what is considered one message. For example, if you have a Basic tier IoT Hub, when you send a telemetry message that's 4 KB **or less**, it counts as one message. If you send a telemetry message of 6 KB, it counts as two messages.

On the Free tier, the metre size is 0.5 KB. If you would send a 6 KB telemetry message, it counts as 12 messages. You can absolutely send messages bigger than 0.5 KB; it will just count as sending more messages.